# ssms script trigger timeout

Tags: ide, timeout, sql-server-2008

Using the SSMS (Sql server management studio) 2008 ide, I frequently get timeouts asking it to script a trigger (or table) to a new query editor window.

This particular time, the error message is Script failed for Trigger 'spbldrom_update'.
Additional information: 
- An exception occurred while executing a Trasact-SQL statement or batch.
- Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. (Microsoft SQL Server)

It takes about 5 minutes for the timeout to occur.

It happened on my prior computer.  It happens on my new Windows XP computer, and my new Windows 7 computer.

I have searched for other people reporting this, but have not found many reports, and no answers, other than increasing the timeout.  But since it takes about 5 minutes to get the timeout, I don't think increasing the timeout will help.

Comment: Enterprise Manager and Query Analyzer create the scripts without any problem, but I have not put them on my new computers.

Comment: I assume your SQL Server runs on the same computer that your management studio is installed. Otherwise it could just be a network or domain controller related problem.

Comment: No, I am connecting to a SQL Servor on another computer. But I have not had trouble scripting stored procs or functions. The problem is limited to tables and triggers.